# Controling axis range on the graphs in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I am using Jupyter to plot graphs and having a issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZVG3.png)

Apparently, Jupyter aligns the x-axis automatically and the numbers are impossible to read.
I would like this graph to be shown like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW6qV.png)

with x-axis range of 1 - 100 and increase by 20

Could anyone help?

Comment: still having weird number listed other than 0-20-40-60-80...

Comment: Check edit.....

Answer (score 0):

Try the `plt.xlim()` and `plt.xticks()` arguments, as seen here:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = np.arange(0,100)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,101,20), size=20)
plt.yticks(size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Edit 1

The numbers you gave me generated a graph with no issue. So I believe you are plotting strings and not floats or ints. You need to convert your columns to float and then plot them:

```py
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
Days = [21.032, 36.218, 36.218]
vDrop = [1.7, 6.3, 6.2]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Days":Days,"vDrop":vDrop})

### Make sure your days and vDrop values are Float and not string
df.Days = df.Days.astype(float)
df.vDrop = df.vDrop.astype(float)


plt.scatter("Days", "vDrop", data=df, s=200, edgecolor="black")
plt.xticks(size=20)
plt.yticks(size=20)
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter Plot]

Also, make sure whatever values you are using for x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 are float... because I don't know where you are getting these values (only what the variable is called) this is the best I can do... place this somewhere before you plot with these variable:

```
x_1 = [float(x) for x in x_1]
y_1 = [float(x) for x in y_1]
x_2 = [float(x) for x in x_2]
y_2 = [float(x) for x in y_2]
```

Comment: still having weird number listed other than 0-20-40-60-80...

Comment: Are you sure what you are using for your x-axis is an int? Are they actually string?

Comment: @Chowlett2, nobody is using numpy to plot graphs, I was using numpy to generate arrays to plot

Comment: plt.scatter(Days_5,V_drop_5)

plt.scatter(Days_6,V_drop_6)

plt.scatter(Days_14,V_drop_14)

plt.scatter(Days_15,V_drop_15)

plt.scatter(Days_21,V_drop_21)

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = np.arange(0,100)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,101,20))

plt.scatter(Days_4,V_drop_4)
x_1=np.linspace(0.00001,28,100)
x_2=np.linspace(28,100,100)
y_O1=(0.2231*(x_1**(-0.072)))*x_1
y_O2=(0.4006*(x_2**(-0.225)))*x_2
plt.plot(x_1,y_O1,color='red')
plt.plot(x_2,y_O2,color='red')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('mV Drop')
plt.show() this is my code!!

Comment: Ok, that code doesn't really help at all because I don't have access to your dataframe. Can you try converting the columns in your dataframe (that have numbers in them) to int? Like `df["Column Name"] = df["Column Name"].astype(int)`

Comment: my data frame is from excel does this cause some issues?

Comment: Can you provide the first 5-10 rows of your dataframe (with the column names) so that I can recreate it?

Comment: Days : 21.032, 36.218, 36.218  /  Vdrop : 1.7, 6.3, 6.2

Comment: Ok, check the edit